# Could someone help me in my code it appears that WWW is obsolete and that I have to use UnityWebReques

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
public IEnumerator CO_Createuser(string user, string email, string pass, string repass, Action<Response> response)
{
    WWWForm form = new WWWForm();
    form.AddField("user", user);
    form.AddField("email", email);
    form.AddField("pass", pass);
    form.AddField("repass", repass);
    WWW w = new WWW("http://localhost:80/Game/createuser.php", form);
    yield return w;
    Debug.Log(w.text);
    response(JsonUtility.FromJson<Response>(w.text));
}
```

I tried this but it didn't work either

```
UnityWebRequestweb = UnityWebRequest.Get("http://localhost:8080/webServicePlataformaDigital/Login.php"+"?alias="+u+"&&password="+p);
```

Comment: All of it in englsh please, this is an English only site.
So, Unity docs give a great explaination of this class, what exactly are you strugging with

Comment: [English is required for all content on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/help/non-english-questions) . Or you can go to [es.so]

Comment: Your two requests do not appear to be equivalent. Study the UnityWebRequest documentation more carefully

Answer (score 1):

First of all, yes, [`WWW`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/WWW.html) is **obsolete** and should not be used anymore.

Then from the documentation you can see that `WWW` if used with a second parameter - like you do

> ```
> WWW w = new WWW("http://localhost:80/Game/createuser.php", form);
> ```

implicitly uses a `POST` request

> The `WWW` class will use `GET` by default and **`POST` if you supply a `postData` parameter**.

However - besides the fact that between these two you are using completely different parameters/fields - you have been trying using a `GET` request with URL embedded fields.

> ```
> UnityWebRequestweb = UnityWebRequest.Get("http://localhost:8080/webServicePlataformaDigital/Login.php"+"?alias="+u+"&&password="+p);
> ```

and even worse - including a password in the URL for everyone to read ;)

---

What you rather want to do is using a `POST` request via [`UnityWebRequest.Post`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Networking.UnityWebRequest.Post.html) doing e.g.

```
var form = new WWWForm();
form.AddField("user", user);
form.AddField("email", email);
form.AddField("pass", pass);
form.AddField("repass", repass);

using(var request = new UnityWebRequest("http://localhost:80/Game/createuser.php", form))
{
    yield return request.SendWebRequest();

    if (request != UnityWebRequest.Result.Success)
    {
        Debug.LogError(request.error);
    }
    else
    {
        Debug.Log("Form upload complete!");
        response(JsonUtility.FromJson<Response>(request.downloadHandler.text));
    }
}
```

Comment: I implemented it but I get an error in this part
response(JsonUtility.FromJson<Response>(request.text));
in the part of (request.text));

Comment: @LisbethAguirre my bad it should be `request.downloadHandler.text`